# Correct vector calculus divergence identity

Tags: vector-fields

I came across this vector calculus identity (in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_2), but also in other sources):

$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot (\vec{B}\times \vec{C}) = \vec{C}\cdot(\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B})-\vec{B}\cdot(\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{C})
$$
where $\vec{\nabla}=(\partial/\partial x,\partial/\partial y,\partial/\partial z)$. However, based on equation (2.5) of the [Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol. II](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_02.html), which states that
$$\vec{A} \cdot (\vec{B}\times \vec{C}) = (\vec{A}\times \vec{B})\cdot \vec{C},$$
the above identity should only contain the first term on the right-hand side.

I'm getting confused. Does anyone know which one is correct and what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Your question  concerns Mathematics (vector  and differential calculus) not Physics.

Comment: I don’t have enough time to write an answer. Griffiths had derived the form in electrodynamics... The form is also known as "back of the cab"

Comment: @BillyIstiak, aren't you confusing this identity with the one involving only cross products?

Comment: @Likely Ooops, yep! I misread :| . I will look it up..

Comment: @BillyIstiak, Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The divergence *operator* looks like a vector but it's still an operator and contains derivatives. Most importantly you have to use the product rule, since the derivative acts on both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. In general for these types of problems working with index notation and Einstein Summation is the best choice. For example
\begin{align*}
\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}) = \partial_i \varepsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k &= \varepsilon_{ijk} \left(\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i} b_k + a_j \frac{\partial b_k}{\partial x_i}\right) \\
&= \varepsilon_{kij} b_k \partial_i a_j - \varepsilon_{jik} a_j \partial_i b_k \\
&= \mathbf{B}\cdot\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right) - \mathbf{A}\cdot\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{B}\right)
\end{align*}